# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel') twitch embed has static imagin video url of stream

Tags: node.js, embed, twitch

as the description says im getting a TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channel') with twitch embed script and it also post a static image and cant seem to get it to show a url clip of the live stream

```
bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
    if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
        console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
        const twitchAnnouncementChannel = newPresence.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === `993751231799500871`)
        const twitchChannel = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#400080")
            .setTitle(`${newPresence.user.tag} is now live on twitch`)
            .setURL(activity.url)
            .setDescription(`**Stream Started**`)
            .setImage(`https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_${activity.url.split("twitch.tv/").pop()}-1920x1080.jpg`)
            .setTimestamp()
        twitchAnnouncementChannel.channel.send({embeds: [twitchChannel, `${newPresence.user.tag} IS NOW LIVE ON TWITCH GO CHECK HIM OUT! @everyone`]})
    }
})
```

})

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMTIy.png)

EDIT::

This code works sends the embed and all but still shuts the bot down with an error see pic below

```
    bot.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
    if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
        console.log(`${newPresence.user} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
        const twitchAnnouncementChannel = newPresence.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === "993751231799500871");
        twitchAnnouncementChannel.send(`hey @everyone **${newPresence.user.name}** IS NOW LIVE ON TWITCH GO CHECK THEM OUT! ${activity.url}`);
        
    }
})
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BiG8.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
const twitchAnnouncementChannel = newPresence.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === `993751231799500871`)
```

Will be a `channel` returned from the channel cache (or fetched if not in the cache)

```
twitchAnnouncementChannel.channel.send({embeds: [twitchChannel, `${newPresence.user.tag} IS NOW LIVE ON TWITCH GO CHECK HIM OUT! @everyone`]})
```

should be

```
twitchAnnouncementChannel.send({embeds: [twitchChannel, `${newPresence.user.tag} IS NOW LIVE ON TWITCH GO CHECK HIM OUT! @everyone`]})
```

You tried to access the property `channel` of a thing that was already a `channel` and a `channel` doesn't have a `channel` as it is a `channel`